# How do I configure the path to the Rust installation when using RustDT with Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, rust

The [RustDT github page](https://github.com/RustDT/RustDT) says this:

> The Rust installation is required for project building. The path to the installation should be configured in Preferences/Rust.

I go into `Preferences/Rust` in Eclipse, but I only see options for text/background colors and formatting settings. Where can I link the path to the installation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, I found the answer. Posting it here so that future people may find it too. When you go to preferences, click on Rust itself, don't expand it.

[image: its here]